# Text Manipulation nestled within a Query (Or ArrayFormula) (Google Sheets)

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to Query some data in my spreadsheet, returning a manufacturer based on product code. We code our products with a three digit suffix that corresponds to different customers. I know the codes but people viewing the sheet may not.

Right now, I'm trying to split the suffix from the product and perform the wuery in the same formula.

I can do this in two steps, splitting the suffix from the code and querying just the suffix, but I want to know if I can do this all in one code. My current formula returns the data I want but it does not fill the entire range of the sheet. I would rather have this happen automatically as the workbook will be dynamic.

My current formula is:

`=QUERY(CxSeries,"select B where C CONTAINS '"&right(Code,3)&"' ")`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/190kom4q0XOJP4UdLTJpZf5tuJCQTflcuokRp_FJ4pBc/edit?usp=sharing

I'm not sure if query is the right way to go about this, but I'd prefer to stick to that (just because i honestly can't wrap my head around ArrayForumlas).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all formulas you have in column C and enter in C7

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(regexextract(D7:D16,"-(\d+)$")+0, {Sheet5!C6:C,Sheet5!B6:B}, 2, 0))
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, thank you. To make sure I understand this correctly, your vlookup checks the D [Product] values against the C values [Suffix] the inputs the B [Customer Name]. I don't understand regular expressions at all, but I assume the expression removes the suffix from the product. And this regular expression returns an array or a range so that vlookup isn't stuck on the result of a formula (one item). And then the ArrayFormula spreads the results across a range rather than one cell. Is that correct? Thank you for your help.